# Is it possible to set up a timer not using events - inside an Akka actor? (typed Akka)

Tags: java, akka, scheduling, actor

The documentation is not too clear on setting up a timer inside an actor. This is the closest information on this I could find: [Scheduling messages to self](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/interaction-patterns.html#scheduling-messages-to-self). However it's not clear from there if we can create an internal timer inside the actor that would just trigger some actor's method every 5 seconds for example (eg checking actor's state and reacting on its change), without receiving and sending events.

If such timer is possible to set up, how reliable would it be? (eg if it can fail while the actor would continue functioning otherwise)

Also if such timer is possible to set up, there supposed to be a possibility of stopping and (re-) starting the timer by the triggered method or another actor's method?

Comment: checkout `Behaviors.withTimers` in the doc https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/interaction-patterns.html#typed-scheduling

Answer (score 0):

If by

> trigger some actor's method every 5 seconds for example (eg checking actor's state and reacting on its change), without receiving and sending events

you mean "schedule a method within the actor to be called without sending a message to the actor", then the answer is no.

Methods in an actor should only ever be executed in direct response to a message sent to the actor (or during the spawning of an actor, but that's arguably effectively a message).  To do otherwise is to throw out (at least) nearly every guarantee the actor model can make.

Comment: The choice I have is either to: 1. schedule actors centrally or 2. schedule actors from inside themselves. I'm seeing central scheduling less reliable because there would need to be a singleton scheduler in Akka cluster - being a single point of failure (even with actor resiliency in the cluster, recovery would take time), also broadcasting from scheduler to all actors in cluster would add complexity and possibility of scheduling message not reaching all actors. Autonomous scheduling from within an actor could be more reliable from this perspective.

Comment: If we use an internal scheduler/timer in an actor without each tick being triggered by a message from a previous tick (as far as I understand this is how it works in Scheduling messages to self - https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/interaction-patterns.html#scheduling-messages-to-self), we can still maintain an event model properly for event sourcing, as we don't need commands to recover the actor state.

Comment: I'm not sure what event sourcing has to do with this: you can have a scheduler send messages without ticks being triggered by a message from a previous tick (use `Timers.startTimerAtFixedRate`) and since the message sent by the timer doesn't have to result in any events, it has no effect on the event model.